# The set $\mathbb{Z}$ is totally ordered

Tags: number-theory, self-learning, integers

Having the following definition of the $\leq$-Relation in $\mathbb{Z}$:

> For $a, b\in \mathbb{Z}$ we define $$ a \leq b : \iff b-a \in \mathbb{N} $$
>   Show that $(\mathbb{Z}, \leq)$ is totally ordered.

I managed to show that $\leq$ as defined above is *reflexive*, *antisymmetric* and *transitive*. I am clueless on how to go about showing that the set is totally ordered.

I remember how it's being done via induction for the $\leq$-Relation in $\mathbb{N}$ but I doubt that I can apply this here. For natural numbers introduce the set: $$ M:= \lbrace n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n \leq m \text{ or } m \leq n \rbrace \text{ for fixated }m \in \mathbb{N} $$ And show that $M = \mathbb{N}$ via induction.

---

I also thought about applying some of the definitions of the relation to introduce $\mathbb{Z}$, namely $$\text{for $c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{N}$}, \ (c,d) \ \sim (e,f) : \iff c+f = d + e $$
which defines an equivalence relation with class $[c,d]$  $$ \mathbb{Z}:= \lbrace [c,d] \mid (c,d) \in \mathbb{N}^2 \rbrace $$

Exhausting google also didn't help me, although I have worked with the terms given in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order

Comment: How are you defining $-$? I suppose $b-a$ means "the unique $x\in\mathbb N$, if it exists, such that $a+x=b$". In that case, it would be equivalent and probably simpler to define $a\leq b$ as $\exists x\in\mathbb N\ a+x=b$.

Comment: Sorry about missing the subtraction statement in my post. If $z=[a,b]$ we define $-z:= [b,a]$ swapping the entries. Thus the subtraction becomes 'addition' by $a+(-b)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that it is totally ordered it just remains to show that for all $a,b$ you have $a \le b$ or $b \le a$. That is, you have to show $a-b $ or $b-a$ is a natural number. This follows from the fact that for each integer $c$ one has $c$ or $-c$ is a natural number. I am not sure if you can use that, but even if not it should not be that hard to establish. How, exactly would depend on how you defined the integers in relation to the natural numbers.

Comment: In that case would it make sense to say if $a-b \in \mathbb{N}$ then $b-a = -1(a-b) \in \mathbb{Z}$ because $\mathbb{Z}$ is constructed to have $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ and the additive inverses of $\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: What you need is rather the other thing. If $a-b \notin \mathbb{N}$, then $-(a-b)\in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use trichotomy property of $\mathbb{Z}$ which says every Integer (it is actually for Reals,so for integers too) number is either positive, negative or zero. By that if you pick $a$ and $b$ $\in \mathbb{Z}$ then $a-b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and thus $a-b \ge0 $ or $\le 0$, $\implies $ $a \ge b$ or $b \ge a$ resp.

Comment: It seems like the purpose of this exercise is to prove the trichotomy property.